# Comparing a string from text file and then printing out the entire line(s)

Tags: c, string, text-files

My goal is to print out every full line from a text file if that line contains a string that is equivalent to user input.

I understand how to find the occurrences of a specific string in a text file, but I am confused as to how to associate that with a specific line. How do I relate my string with the specific line that it is in?

My initial thought was to store each line in an array and then print out that line if the user string is somewhere in that line.

However each line is a different size, so I was wondering if it is possible for me to initially divide my entire text file into x number of lines and then use a loop to go through each line and search for that string?

Comment: Is there a limit for the line length? You could, perhaps, define the array large enough for the longest line; otherwise you will need dynamic allocation (`malloc()` and friends).

Comment: There is a limit for the line length. Should I read the characters until I reach a '\n' and then store that as a string?

Comment: Yes, `fgets()` does just exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file pointer of the starting of the line in a temp variable before starting new line compare

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I currently have my program searching for strings in general (independent of lines) and I don't understand how to manipulate the lines.

Comment: can you share part of your code(of searching the string) for more understanding